# Javascript pythagoras function shows as undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner and don't understand why the following shows as undefined.

The following is my script:

```
 function pythagoras() {
     function solvepy(form) {
         var a = parseFloat(form.a.value);
         var b = parseFloat(form.b.value);
         c.value = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
     }

     function pythagoras(form) {
         var aInput = document.getElementById("a");
         var bInput = document.getElementById("b");
     }
     var result = displayResult();
 }

 function displayResult(a, b, c) {
     var div = document.getElementById("result");
     div.innerHTML = "Triangle: a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ". c = " + c;
 }
```

The following is my body:

```
 <form>
  <label for="a">Enter lengths for sides a: </label>
  <input type="number" id="a" size="3">
  <label for="b"> and b: </label>
  <input type="number" id="b" size="3"><br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Compute c!">
 </form>
 <div id="result">
 </div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function? You are never returning a value from any function, nor are you passing any values to `displayResult`, and `c` inside `solvepy` is not defined. There is lots of stuff that is no correct, so I recommend to read a tutorial about functions, or JavaScript in general: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions, http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html. Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn basics of a language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

Javascript :

```
// Set global variables, so they can be accessed trough all functions
var a, b, c;

function calculate() {
         a = parseFloat(document.pythagora.a.value);
         b = parseFloat(document.pythagora.b.value);
         c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
         displayResult(a,b,c);
}
function displayResult(a, b, c) {
     var div = document.getElementById("result");
     div.innerHTML = "Triangle: a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ". c = " + c;
}
```

Body

```
<form name="pythagora">
  <label for="a">Enter lengths for sides a: </label>
  <input type="number" id="a" size="3">
  <br>
  <label for="b"> and b: </label>
  <input type="number" id="b" size="3"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Compute c!" onClick="calculate();">
</form>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

[Here is a working example link..(click here)](http://jsfiddle.net/RRgSW/)

Comment: Why are you using global variables in your example? You don't even need them.

Comment: That's added initially while trying to make the posted example work .. later I changed the functions etc. but variables were left there. Since the user is beginner it doesn't hurt to show some info about how JS is working ..

Comment: Sure, but in general global variables should be avoided, so showing bad practices is not a good thing ;)

Comment: I wouldn't go that far and call global variables "bad practice" .. lot of the applications wouldn't work without them. When learning a new language it's good to learn everything and with time sharpen your skills trough optimization and better understanding of  different patterns etc. :)